# GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer and 'Type id handling not implemented for type' error

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind, spring-data-redis

I am using GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer for reading and writing data in Redis and it works great for most part.

However I have a special case where I want to store one of the object as just binary serialized form.
I implemented custom Serializer and Deserializer for this class types and registerd the module in object mapper used by GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer but its not working and I see below error.
Seems like something is missing and your help is appreciated to solve this.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not write JSON: Type id handling not implemented for type com.abc.def.Child
 (through reference chain: com.abc.def.Parent["child"]); 
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
 Type id handling not implemented for type com.abc.def.Child (through reference chain: com.abc.def.Parent["child"])
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:88)
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Type id handling not implemented for type com.abc.def.Child
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(JsonSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:507)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
```

The java class that i need to read/write here is like this -

```
public class Parent extends SomeOtherObject {

    @JsonSerialize(using = ChildSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ChildDeserializer.class)   
    private com.abc.def.Child child;    

.
.
.
    
}
```